# How to route to a custom function in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I've create a function in **UsersController** named **changepassword** and also added following code to routes/web.php

```
Route::any("/users/changepassword","UsersController@changepassword")->name("users.changepassword");
```

But when I trying to access **/users/changepassword** go to function show rather than changepassword.

Comment: Can you place this line `Route::any("/users/changepassword","UsersController@changepassword")->name("users.changepassword");` before the one of show method in the routes file ? and test again!

Comment: Please show the complete routes file

Comment: @Maraboc it work fine now. Thank you.